# using tweepy to retrieve data containing a particular hashtag

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to use tweepy to retrieve tweets of a particular hashtag. This is my code:

```
file = open('pc_week1.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(file)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(extractor.search, q='#pyeongchang2018', count=100, lang='en', since='2017-12-01', until='2017-12-07').items():
    writer.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

When I define the 'until' parameter, the code returns an empty dataframe. But when I DON'T define 'until', it retrieves all tweets since the date specified. The only thing is, I'm looking to get only a week's worth of data (2017-12-01~2017-12-07). Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
I tried putting in a different date for 'until' parameter:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(extractor.search, q='#pyeongchang2018', count=100, lang='en', since='2017-12-01', until='2017-12-15').items():
    writer.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

And it DIDN'T return an empty df like before, but instead the results indicate that the until parameter was ignored. Here's a snippet of the results:

```
    Date                Tweet
0   2018-01-25 08:35:21 b"RT @AFP: WATCH: A dozen North Korean female ...
1   2018-01-25 08:34:19 b"RT @AFP: WATCH: A dozen North Korean female ...
2   2018-01-25 08:33:29 b'Amazing @Aerialskier what an achievement! Go...
3   2018-01-25 08:32:29 b'RT @cnni: The new police force in charge of ...
4   2018-01-25 08:32:12 b'North Korean ice hockey teams arrives in Sou...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `since` and `until` parameters correctly, but the problem is that Tweepy can't return data older than 7 days.

Comment: The standard search API from Twitter only supports 7 day of history (not 2 weeks). The premium API offers a 30-day search option, but you won't be able to access Tweets from December 2017 at this point.

Comment: @AndyPiper is retrieving tweets specifically different from retrieving most liked or most retweeted tweets? In a different project few days ago, I was able to retrieve most liked/most retweeted tweet from August 2017

Comment: I'm not sure how you would have done that - there's no Twitter API for that. I assume you were pulling a user timeline and looking for popular Tweets?

Comment: @AndyPiper sorry about the late response, but yes that's exactly what I was doing, and I was able to pull out tweets from 2017